# How to de-reference an array in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, dereference

```
sub main
{
    my (@A) = @_;
}
main([1,3,5,7]);
```

The array has been input using the above code. I am unable to obtain the original array; when I simply `print "@A"`, I get the reference.  But, I can't find a way to obtain the actual array from this. Can anyone please throw some light on what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass an array reference (which is a scalar value) to the sub.  Your `@A` variable is an array-of-arrays.  There is only one element of the array, and it is the array reference you passed to the sub.  If you want to print the elements of what you passed, you can use the `@{ }` syntax:

```
print "@{ $A[0] }\n";
```

However, since you just passed an array ref, that is not likely what you want.
One way to retrieve that is to assign it to a scalar variable in the sub.  Then you can deference it and assign it to an array variable using `@{ }`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

main([1,3,5,7]);

sub main
{
    my ($aref) = @_;
    my @A = @{ $aref };
    print "@A\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
1 3 5 7
```